# How to set the number of of rows in a line chart in chart.js?

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

Given a label of dates from the pass 9 days and a data set of numbers(2.5,1.5 etc), I want the the numbers/labels at the y-axis to be whole numbers from 1-5 while maintaining the points. What I'm trying to say is I want to have a fixed number of rows in the grid and I'm clueless on how to do it. Can anyone help me?

**Current Graph:**

[image]

**Expected Graph:**

[image: ar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Option 1/2: stacked

The shortest way:

```
    yAxes: [{
      stacked: true,
    }]
```

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#stacked-bar-chart

```js
/* data */
var data = {
  labels: ["Africa", "Asia", "Europe", "America"],
  datasets: [{
    /* data */
    label: "Data label",
    backgroundColor: ["#3e95cd", "#8e5ea2","#3cba9f", '#1d49b8'],
    data: [5.6,6.7,7.5, 8.6]
  }]
};


var options = {
  responsive: true,
  title: {
    text: 'Hello',
    display: true
  },
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      stacked: false,
      ticks: {

      },
    }],
    yAxes: [{
      stacked: true,
    }]
  }
};

var myChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("chart"), {
  type: 'bar',
  data: data,
  options: options
});
```

```html
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
```

### Option 2/2: step-size

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html#step-size

More control ==> set step size (To `1` in your example):

```
    yAxes: [{
      stacked: true,
      ticks: {
        stepSize: 1
      }
    }]
```

```js
/* data */
var data = {
  labels: ["Africa", "Asia", "Europe", "America"],
  datasets: [{
    /* data */
    label: "Data label",
    backgroundColor: ["#3e95cd", "#8e5ea2","#3cba9f", '#1d49b8'],
    data: [5.0,6.7,7.5, 8.6]
  }]
};


var options = {
  responsive: true,
  title: {
    text: 'Hello',
    display: true
  },
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      stacked: false,
      ticks: {

      },
    }],
    yAxes: [{
      stacked: false,
      ticks: {
        stepSize: 1
      }
    }]
  }
};

var myChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("chart"), {
  type: 'bar',
  data: data,
  options: options
});
```

```html
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
```